# How to set “Other Linker Flags” as Xcode in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, robovm

In my RoboVM project, I used some third part frameworks. But they need add -ObjC to "Other Linker Flags", otherwise it will crash.

I know how to add that in Xcode, but in Eclipse, how can I do that?

Comment: See if this is what you're looking for ... 
Select the menu: Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler ---
There you will find several check boxes under the heading "Classfile Generation" --- source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483315/where-do-you-configure-eclipse-java-compiler-javac-flags

Comment: @Bret Thank you.But I don't think it's the right one.

Comment: What framework requires this?  Maybe I can review their documentation to see what is required ...

Comment: Eclipse comes with a built-in compiler that is fairly well guarded, it appears.  But, you have other options to run javac with compiler flags 

--- Check this SO question and its answers -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987694/how-to-run-javac-from-eclipse -- you're very likely going to need to take one of the approaches listed ---

Or, in the very least, begin doing some research in this direction ---

Or, use another IDE: RoboVM Studio?  Android Studio?  IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up -ObjC to "Other Linker Flags" is only possible using Xcode, no such thing is possible in RoboVM so far