# java generics: compiler error not shown in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I have these classes:

```
public class EntityDataModel<T extends AbstractEntity>
{
    ...
}

public abstract class BarChartBean<E extends ChartEntry, T>
{
    protected EntityDataModel<? extends T> currentModel;

    ...
}
```

I can compile and run this code on eclipse without problem, but when I invoke `mvn compile`, this error is thrown:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project edea2: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Develop\...\BarChartBean.java:[53,30] error: type argument ? extends T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2
[ERROR] where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
[ERROR] T#1 extends Object declared in class BarChartBean
[ERROR] T#2 extends AbstractEntity declared in class EntityDataModel
```

The error is pretty self-explanatory, and theoretically speaking, javac is right and eclipse compiler is wrong.

Why there's such a difference?

Here you are the details of the environment:

- Eclipse

  - Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
  - jdk 1.8.0_71
  - Compiler compliance level: 1.8
  - [image: Errors/Warnings]
- Maven

  - Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
  - Maven home: C:\Develop\tools\apache-maven-3.3.3
  - Java version: 1.8.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  - Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\jre
  - Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
  - OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
  - maven-compiler-plugin:

    ```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ```

**Question**: How can I *align* the eclipse compiler behavior to javac (but I don't want to use javac in eclipse)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's yet another mismatch between the Eclipse Java compiler and the official JDK compiler [(because these are different indeed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler). And javac is not always the [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100552/illegalaccesserror-when-using-a-public-method-reference-of-a-package-private-cla) actor in this game, you can indeed hit a javac bug not occurring in the Eclipse compiler.

A similar issue has already been reported: [**Bug 456459**: Discrepancy between Eclipse compiler and javac - Enums, interfaces, and generics](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456459).

To align Maven with Eclipse, you can [configure](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html) the `maven-compiler-plugin` as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Basically, you are telling Maven to use the Eclipse Java compiler. I was able to reproduce your issue and applying this configuration the Maven build was then fine. However, I would not recommend this approach.

On the other hand, to configure Eclipse to use the JDK compiler is a bit more difficult, basically because the Eclipse compiler is part of the IDE features. A procedure is explained in the Stack Overflow q/a: [How to run Javac from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987694/how-to-run-javac-from-eclipse).

Comment: Thanks, just knowing it's a ECJ bug is enough. I opened a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496911).

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, thanks for the bug report. As argued there, I'm not convinced that ecj is wrong. JLS 4.5 defines well-formedness of a parameterized type via capturing the type arguments. Such capture by definition conforms to the upper bounds of the corresponding type variable. So, how can `cap#1 extends glb(AbstractEntity,T)` violate the bound `extends AbstractEntity`? This type could be ill-formed by contradictory bounds (i.e., undefined glb), but I don't see any such contradiction. So, why should a compiler reject this?

Comment: Regarding `plexus-compiler-eclipse`: I'm not sure how this plugin is maintained and what versions of ecj it would pull in. More hints on using ecj outside Eclipse are collected at https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_use_JDT_outside_Eclipse_to_compile_Java_code.3F which includes the option to use tycho, which updates the ecj-dependency quite regularly.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I'll take a look, definitely. Thank you, again :)