# Unresolved compilation problems when generating WAR file using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I generate my WAR file using mvn clean install , some classes throw the following error msg:

> public Person deletePers(String paramString1, String paramString2)   {
>       throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problems: \n\tTransactional cannot be resolved to a type\n.......;   }

But if I generate my WAR file in Eclipse (file > export as War File), I don't get the above error. Anyone know how to solve this?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>PPS</groupId>
<artifactId>PPS</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>   <!-- Usata da Hibernate 4 per LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>    <!-- Hibernate -->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

Comment: could you give us your pom.xml ?

Comment: Examine the build log to find the "unresolved compilation errors"

Comment: @vincent see updated post for pom.xml

Comment: @JimGarrison Where can i find the build log?

Comment: In the console output in Eclipse when you do the build.

Comment: You have compilation failures that you need to fix. We can't tell why you have those failures without seeing all the code in your project. But that's way outside the scope of this question. No idea why it's working for you in eclipse, but you really need to fix these failures for maven anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem Part:**

This is happening because eclipse is using its **own compiler**.

Eclipse has implemented its **own compiler** called as **Eclipse Compiler for Java** (ECJ).

It is **different from the javac**, the compiler that is shipped with Sun JDK. One **notable difference** is that the **Eclipse compiler lets you run code** that **didn't actually properly compile**.

If the block of code with the error is never ran, your program will run fine. Otherwise, it will throw an exception indicating that you tried to run code that doesn't compile.

Another difference is that the Eclipse compiler allows for **incremental** builds from within the Eclipse IDE, that is, all code is compiled **as soon as you finish typing.**

=============================

**Solution Part:**

Unfortunately,there is **no quick way** in Eclipse to switch to **Javac (from Sun /Oracle).** You cannot simply choose javac from a dropdown or similar in eclipse.

**FYi:** But this is [very simple](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/java-compiler.html#compiler) in **IntelliJ IDEA**.

But, you can achieve this using **Ant** tasks or **External Tools Configuration**.

Both the above approaches are clearly explained [in this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987694/how-to-run-javac-from-eclipse).

Comment: Yeah I understand. Even if run my maven command on command prompt, I still get this issues of compilation. Any solution for this?

Comment: When I run mvn clean install, it generates a jar file also since I have added this config:


    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 If i do the above solution, I don't think I will get this jar file? Am i right? This jar file is very important for me.

Comment: Both are irrelavent, you will get your jar ;-)

Comment: "First you should change the "-d" argument to the binary folder of the built project"
What is the binary folder ?

Comment: bin is short for binary folder - the folderwhere you have your compiled classes

Comment: I don't have a bin folder in my project!